# How single sign on (sso) work for login to same device?

Tags: single-sign-on

As per I know, SSO is a one time login for all the applications connected.

**But what does it mean that after sign-up user is always able to use the same device's auto login?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSO means, you will have a single Identity Provider, which will provide authorization to multiple clients.

Your clients can be An angular app, React app, web api, mobile application etc.

OpenId connect(oidc) and oAuth 2 define how to do SSO. There are providers like Identiy Server 4, which implements what is specified by oidc and oAuth2.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How is this related to "the same device's auto login"?

Comment: Same device auto login can be done by setting up cookies. The way SSO works is, when you want to access a resource in your client which needs authorization. You will be redirected to the Identity provider site, where you will log in with your credentials. This identity provider validates your credentials and issue an Id_token to the respective client. Then redirects you back to the client resource. To summarise, this identity provide can handle multiple clients, each one has separate setting like clientId, Secret, grant type etc.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Don't use the comment section for this